# Unary Enumeration

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I would like to have an `enumerate` list, **with the numbers expressed in unary**. That is, "1" would be represented as `•`, "3" as `•••`, and "8" as `•••••|•••`.

I'm able to print the dots already, and that's working fine:

```
\newcommand{\xxdot}{\textbullet} % The dot character to use
\newcounter{loopcntr} % A one-off counter for \forloop

\newcommand{\xxdots}[1]{% Print #1 dots in a row
    \ifthenelse{#1>5}{% If there are more than five, break them into groups
        \xxdots{5}\textpipe\xxdots{\number\numexpr#1-5\relax}% By printing five, then a pipe, then the rest
    }{% Otherwise, just print that many dots
        \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{\xxdot}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\xdots}[1]{\textnormal{\xxdots{#1}}} % Wrap it in textnormal style
```

However, I have no idea how to make `enumerate` use this. Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2292/169121), I tried redefining `\theenumi`:

```
\renewcommand\theenumi{\xdots{\arabic{enumi}}}
```

But this went badly wrong:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@currentlabel.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.376 ^^I\item My text here ...
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

How can I apply my unary-printing code to the `enumerate` label?

EDIT: Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124983/169121), I tried this:

```
\newcommand*\unary[1]{\expandafter\@unary\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@unary[1]{\xdots{\the\numexpr#1\relax}}
```

And it seems to work! As in, this produces the correct output:

```
\newcounter{test}
\setcounter{test}{8}
\unary{test}
```

However, the MWE still throws a bunch of errors.

MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\xxdot}{\textbullet} % The dot character to use
\newcounter{loopcntr} % A one-off counter for \forloop

\newcommand{\xxdots}[1]{% Print #1 dots in a row
    \ifthenelse{#1>5}{% If there are more than five, break them into groups
        \xxdots{5}\textpipe\xxdots{\number\numexpr#1-5\relax}% By printing five, then a pipe, then the rest
    }{% Otherwise, just print that many dots
        \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{\xxdot}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\xdots}[1]{\textnormal{\xxdots{#1}}} % Wrap it in textnormal style

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\unary[1]{\expandafter\@unary\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@unary[1]{\xdots{\the\numexpr#1\relax}}
\makeatother

%\renewcommand\theenumi{\unary{enumi}} % This crashes and burns

\begin{document}

Unary works normally: \xdots{1}, \xdots{3}, \xdots{8}.

It even works with a counter.

\newcounter{test}
\setcounter{test}{8}
\unary{test}

But in a list:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item My text here my text here
    \item More text more text
    \item Even more text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467205/121799)?

Comment: @marmot I was not, but it seems to offer good solutions!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `enumitem` package is your friend. You can define a new list style, which I have called `unerate`, and then make this list style use your `\unary` code. To achieve this it is enough to add the following lines to your code:

```
\let\realItem\item
\newcommand\unerateItem{\refstepcounter{uneratei}\realItem[\unary{uneratei}]}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{unerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[unerate]{label=\alph*, before=\let\item\unerateItem }
```

So this redefines `\item` to be `\unerateItem` and this, in turn, uses the "real" `\item` with `\unary` applied to the list environment counter, which is called `uneratei`. With this in place, the code

```
\begin{unerate}
    \item My text here my text here
    \item More text more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
\end{unerate}
```

produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\xxdot}{\textbullet} % The dot character to use
\newcounter{loopcntr} % A one-off counter for \forloop

\newcommand{\xxdots}[1]{% Print #1 dots in a row
    \ifthenelse{#1>5}{% If there are more than five, break them into groups
        \xxdots{5}\textpipe\xxdots{\number\numexpr#1-5\relax}% By printing five, then a pipe, then the rest
    }{% Otherwise, just print that many dots
        \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{\xxdot}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\xdots}[1]{\textnormal{\xxdots{#1}}} % Wrap it in textnormal style

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\unary[1]{\expandafter\@unary\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@unary[1]{\xdots{\the\numexpr#1\relax}}
\makeatother

\let\realItem\item
\newcommand\unerateItem{\refstepcounter{uneratei}\realItem[\unary{uneratei}]}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{unerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[unerate]{label=\alph*, before=\let\item\unerateItem }

\begin{document}

  \begin{unerate}
    \item My text here my text here
    \item More text more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
    \item Even more text
  \end{unerate}

\end{document}
```

You can now use `enumitem` to style these environments to your heart's content.

The code above will not let you nest `unerate` environments. If this is required let me know and I will update it - it's not difficult, but requires a little extra work.

Comment: Perfect! I'll wait a bit longer before accepting, but this seems to fulfill my needs perfectly. (As you surmised, I won't need to nest these environments.)

Comment: Actually, one thing to note: this _does not work_ if the `hyperref` package is included first. It works fine if `hyperref` is included later, though.

Comment: @DraconisAccording to its manual, you should always load hyperref last :)

Comment: I wonder how you read `unerate` ...

Answer (score 15):

I recycled [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467208/121799) and slightly extended it to get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\nbullets}[2][\textbullet]{%
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(mod(\X,5))}]in {1,...,#2}
{\ifnum\X>1%
\ifnum\Y=1%
$\vert$\fi%
\fi%
#1}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\nbullets{\value{enumi}}}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item first
 \item second
 \item third
 \item fourth
 \item fifth
 \item sixth
 \item seventh
 \item last 
\end{enumerate}

Nestable:
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\nbullets[*]{\value{enumii}}}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item first
 \item second
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
  \item d
  \item e
  \item f
 \end{enumerate}
 \item third
 \item fourth
 \item fifth
 \item sixth
 \item seventh
 \item last 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A version for Stefan. (`\TCS` is essentially from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467809/121799).)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\nbullets}[2][\textbullet]{%
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(mod(\X,5))}]in {1,...,#2}
{\ifnum\X>1%
\ifnum\Y=1%
$\vert$\fi%
\fi%
#1}}
\newcommand{\TCS}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,#1]
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(mod(\X,5))}]in {1,...,#2}
{\ifnum\Y=0
\draw (\X*0.5ex+0.3ex,0) -- ++(-2.8ex,2ex);
\else
\draw (\X*0.5ex+0.3ex,0) -- ++(0,2ex);
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\TCS{\value{enumi}}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\nbullets{\value{enumii}}}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item first
 \item second
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
  \item d
  \item e
  \item f
 \end{enumerate}
 \item third
 \item fourth
 \item fifth
 \item sixth
 \item seventh
 \item last 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 How would you create an Enumeration with Tally marks in this way?

Comment: @Stefan [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467809/121799) starts with "something like this?" ;-)

Comment: Thank you both for the link and your extended answer.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an expandable `\unifive` macro:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,enumitem,tipa}

\usepackage{showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\unifive}{m}
 {% #1 should be an integer
  \draconis_unifive:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \draconis_unifive:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 > 5 }
   {
    \unifivefive
    \draconis_unifive:e { \int_eval:n { #1 - 5 } }
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \unifiveone }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \draconis_unifive:n { e }

\NewDocumentCommand{\unifivefive}{}
 {
  \unifiveone\unifiveone\unifiveone
  \unifiveone\unifiveone\unifivebar
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\unifiveone}{}{\textbullet}
\NewDocumentCommand{\unifivebar}{}{\textpipe}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unifivecount}[1]{\expandafter\@unifivecount\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@unifivecount}[1]{\unifive{#1}}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\unifivecount}{\@unifivecount}{\unifive{10}}
\makeatother

\newlist{unerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[unerate]{label=\unifivecount*,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{unerate}
  \item My text here my text here
  \item More text more text
  \item Even more text
  \item Even more text
  \item Even more text
  \item Even more text
  \item Even more text
  \item Even more text
  \item Even more text
  \item Even more text
\end{unerate}

\unifive{42}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You don't need explicit loops to generate a number of bullets

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi\space}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\expandafter\zzm\romannumeral\the\value{enumi}000\relax}

\def\zzm#1{\if m#1\textbullet\expandafter\zzm\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item My text here my text here
    \item More text more text
    \item Even more text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```